# Using keyup event to apply changes dynamically to multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a basic JavaScript search functionality. So I have a couple of divs and an input search field:

```
<div class="notes">
  <div class="firstNote">FIRST NOTE</div>
  <div class="secondNote">SECOND NOTE</div>
  <div class="thirdNote">THIRD NOTE</div>
  <div class="fourthNote">THIRDDD NOTE</div>
  <div class="fifthNote">THIRL NOTE</div>
</div>
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```

The idea is that when the user types in the search box, it checks what they typed against the `innerHTML` values of the divs inside the parent `notes` div. While those values match, it should apply the `searched` class to those divs where the matching value is found. And then hide all the other divs by giving them `display:none`. Once it stops finding a match, it should remove the `searched` class from all the divs and display them all again by giving them `display:block`.

The trouble is that this works only for the first div it finds where there is a match. I've created a couple of them starting with the letters 'THIR' for testing. If I start typing 'thir', it only shows (i.e. applies the 'searched' class to) the first div whose text matches (the one with the `thirdNote` class), but not the other two even though they still also match. Here's the JS code:

```
const notes = document.querySelectorAll(".notes div");
const search = document.querySelector(".search input");
let count = 0; //detecting the number of times the user typed in the input field

search.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    let x = 1; //will use this to compare the values of the search box and the divs
    if(e.which === 16) //if the user presses Shift, don't do anything
      return;
    if(e.which !== 8) //if pressed anything but Backspace, increase the count
      count++;
    else if(e.which === 8 && count >= 1) { // otherwise decrease the count
      count--;
  } 
  const textSearched = this.value; //what the user typed in the searchbox
//if there is no text in the search box, remove the 'searched' class from all the divs, show all of them, and reset x back to 1
  if(count === 0 || textSearched === ""){
    notes.forEach(function(el){
      if(el.style.display === "none")
        el.style.display = "block";
      if(el.classList.contains("searched"))
        el.classList.remove("searched");
    });
    x = 1;
  }
  notes.forEach((body) => {
  //while the search box and the div text values match, and x is not greater than the div text length, add the 'searched' class and increment x
     while(textSearched.substring(0, x).toLowerCase() === body.innerHTML.substring(0, x).toLowerCase() && x <= body.innerHTML.length) {
         body.classList.add("searched");
       x++;
//if count is less than x, it means there is a match. So show all the matching divs, and hide all the other ones
       if(count < x) {
         notes.forEach((el) => {
           if(!el.classList.contains("searched"))
             el.style.display = "none";
           else
             el.style.display = "block";
         });
      }
// if count is equal or greater than x, it means no more matching, so show all the divs and remove the 'searched' class
       else {
        notes.forEach(function(el){
            if(el.style.display === "none")
              el.style.display = "block";
            if(el.classList.contains("searched"))
              el.classList.remove("searched");
        });
       }
     } 
  }); 
});
```

Here is a working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tpxd5cqm/4/

Thanks!

Comment: To save some time trying to figure out your logic, I see you're doing lower casing on the comparisons, but other than that, what is your criteria for a match?  Are you partial matching, or does the search have to match entirely?  From re-reading the question, it seems like you're matching on the string starts with the search?

Comment: Do you really need to preserve the separate classes for each child of `.notes`? That seems kind of odd, and will make things more difficult than they'd have to be

Comment: @Taplar  yes, the idea is that as long as what the user is typing matches with the text in one of the divs, it should be a match. For example, if the text reads 'first note', and user starts typing 'fir', it matches. But if they type, for example, 'firy', then it no longer matches

Comment: @Snow No, it doesn't have to be this way, it's just how I tried it. No special need for the separate classes for each child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'd do: toggle a class on the parent container when matching search elements are detected, and remove the class when there are no matches, or when the input is empty. When the parent class is active, highlight all `.searched` children, and hide all non-`.searched` children:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.notes');
const notes = [...container.children];
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  // Wait for the input field to contain its final value:
  setTimeout(checkInput);
});
const checkInput = () => {
  const value = input.value.toLowerCase();
  const matchingNotes = notes.filter(note => note.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(value));
  if (!value || matchingNotes.length === 0) {
    container.classList.remove('searchActive');
    return;
  }
  container.classList.add('searchActive');
  for (const note of notes) {
    if (matchingNotes.includes(note)) {
      note.classList.add('searched');
    } else {
      note.classList.remove('searched');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.searchActive > .searched {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.searchActive > *:not(.searched) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="notes">
  <div>FIRST NOTE</div>
  <div>SECOND NOTE</div>
  <div>THIRD NOTE</div>
  <div>THIRDDD NOTE</div>
  <div>THIRL NOTE</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```